# Change the URL in the address bar using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have written the following to do AJAX requests in my app:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('ul#ui-ajax-tabs li:first').addClass('selected');

    $('#ui-ajax-tabs li a').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $("#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("selected");

        $(this).parents('li').addClass("loading");

        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var link = $(this);
        console.log(url);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (responseHtml) {
                $('div#ui-tab-content').html($(responseHtml).find('div#ui-tab-content > div#ui-ajax-html'));
                $(link).parents('li').addClass('selected');
                $("#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("loading");
            },
            error: function () {
                $('div#ui-tab-content').html('<div class="message error">Sorry that page doesn\'t exist</div>');
                $(link).parents('li').addClass('selected');
                $("#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("loading");
            }
        });

    });

});
```

However I also want to change the url in the address bar to match what I just loaded in. I have looked around at some demos using the new HTML5 History API @ http://html5demos.com/history but it's not making any sense.

Could someone show an example of how I could use the new history stuff in my code? Would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to change the URL (without hashes) and staying in the same page is by using HTML5. And you're better off using a plugin than writing your own.

In your case, you would need to 'push' a new History state whenever you call the Ajax page.

Maybe you can take a look at this plugin `History.js`:
https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

Its usage is very simple, as you can see in the Docs.

```
(function(window,undefined){

    // Prepare
    var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
         // History.js is disabled for this browser.
         // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
        return false;
    }

    // Bind to StateChange Event
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
        var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
        History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
    });

    // Change our States
    History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"); // logs {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
    History.pushState({state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2"); // logs {state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2"
    History.replaceState({state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"
    History.pushState(null, null, "?state=4"); // logs {}, '', "?state=4"
    History.back(); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"
    History.back(); // logs {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
    History.back(); // logs {}, "Home Page", "?"
    History.go(2); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"

})(window);
```

Comment: Could you show an example of how to use this plugin with my code I posted? I'm very new to this and this is my first bit of AJAX so examples would be great. Much appreciated. Thanks